# Can you use Math.max with an array?

Tags: java, arrays, math

```
package prova1;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author OOO
 */
public class Prova1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array[] = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert number");
            array[i] = Integer.parseInt(input);
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Math.max(array));

    }

}
```

Comment: You can read documentation on that method and then no need to ask such questions

Answer (score 8):

> Can you use Math.max with an array?

No, but...

If you're using Java 8, you can use [streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

```
Arrays.stream(array).max().getAsInt()
```

Otherwise you can write a simple utility method to do it for you:

```
public static int max(int... array) {
    if (array.length == 0) {
        // ...
    }

    int max = array[0];

    for (int a : array) {
        if (a > max)
            max = a;
    }

    return max;
}
```

Comment: Proposal: change `int[]` to `int...`

Answer (score 2):

```
 // Initializing array of integers 
        Integer[] num = { 2, 4, 7, 5, 9 }; 

  // using Collections.max() to find minimum element 
        // using only 1 line. 
int max = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(num));
```